# error in create table for android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

in this class i am going to declare table and column for this table but

```
public static abstract class Wish_list_Table implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "WISH_LIST";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_PHOTO = "PHOTO";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_PRICE = "PRICE";
    public static final String COL_LATITUDE = "LATITUDE";
    public static final String COL_LONGITUDE = "LONGITUDE";
    public static final String COL_LOCATION = "LOCATION";
    public static final String COL_DESC = "DESC";

}
```

and this is query for create table ...and this is log cat content.....

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.info.wishlist.WishListProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEWISH_LIST": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEWISH_LIST(_idINTEGER PRIMARYKEY,NAMETEXT,DESCTEXT,LOCATIONREAL
,LATITUDEREAL,LONGITUDEREAL,PRICEINTEGER,DATEINTEGER,PHOTOBLOB)

```
public static final String CREATE_DB = "CREATE TABLE"
        + Wish_list_Table.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Wish_list_Table._ID
        + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Wish_list_Table.COL_NAME + "TEXT,"
        + Wish_list_Table.COL_DESC + "TEXT," + Wish_list_Table.COL_LOCATION
        + "REAL," + Wish_list_Table.COL_LATITUDE + "REAL,"
        + Wish_list_Table.COL_LONGITUDE + "REAL,"
        + Wish_list_Table.COL_PRICE + "INTEGER," + Wish_list_Table.COL_DATE
        + "INTEGER," + Wish_list_Table.COL_PHOTO + "BLOB)";
```

Comment: You need space between column and text. ex : (_id INTEGER,NAME TEXT ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put space between column name and type

```
public static final String CREATE_DB = "CREATE TABLE "// note the space
+ Wish_list_Table.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Wish_list_Table._ID
    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Wish_list_Table.COL_NAME + " TEXT,"
    + Wish_list_Table.COL_DESC + " TEXT," + Wish_list_Table.COL_LOCATION
    + " REAL," + Wish_list_Table.COL_LATITUDE + " REAL,"
    + Wish_list_Table.COL_LONGITUDE + " REAL,"
    + Wish_list_Table.COL_PRICE + " INTEGER," + Wish_list_Table.COL_DATE
    + " INTEGER," + Wish_list_Table.COL_PHOTO + " BLOB)";
```

Answer (score 0):

i got solution...it's require space each and every field start and end.

```
public static final String CREATE_DB = " CREATE TABLE "
        + Wish_list_Table.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Wish_list_Table._ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + Wish_list_Table.COL_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + Wish_list_Table.COL_DESC + " TEXT, " + Wish_list_Table.COL_LOCATION
        + " REAL, " + Wish_list_Table.COL_LATITUDE + " REAL, "
        + Wish_list_Table.COL_LONGITUDE + " REAL, "
        + Wish_list_Table.COL_PRICE + " INTEGER, " + Wish_list_Table.COL_DATE
        + " INTEGER, " + Wish_list_Table.COL_PHOTO + " BLOB)";
```